# a folder and the main.py are by default in there, what do they do and are they important (if not to delete them )?

Tags: python, pycharm

I recently started coding in Pycharm and a folder and the main.py are by default in there, what do they do and are they important (if not to delete them )?

Comment: Most IDEs by default generate a "main" file as a "hello world" starting point. You can just delete it. What folder are you talking about though?

Answer (score 0):

Your venv folder is the local python environment for that directory, so don't delete that, but main.py is fine to delete, it's just made as a default starting file. You can easily remove it and start your own under whatever name you choose.